# determine which of the given sets are closed in $\mathcal{B}[a,b]$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functions, metric-spaces

> Let $\mathcal{B}[a,b]$ be the set of bounded functions from $[a,b]$ to $\mathbb{R}$, $\mathcal{R}[a,b] = \{f \in \mathcal{B}[a,b] : \text{ $f$ is Riemann integrable}\},$ $\mathcal{C}^1 [a,b] := \{f \in \mathcal{B}[a,b] : \text{ $f$ is differentiable}\},$ and $\mathcal{P}[a,b] := \{f \in \mathcal{B}[a,b] : \text{ $f$ is a polynomial }\}$. Determine, with proof, which of the following sets are closed in $(\mathcal{B}[a,b], d_\infty),$ where $d_\infty$ is the supremum metric: $\mathcal{C}^1 [a,b], \mathcal{R}[a,b], $ or $\mathcal{P}[a,b]$.

I think $\mathcal{R}[a,b]$ is closed but $\mathcal{P}[a,b]$ and $\mathcal{C}^1 [a,b]$ are not. Perhaps a sequence like $f_n = x + x^2 + \cdots + x^n \,\forall n,$ which is contained in $\mathcal{P}[a,b]$ does not converge to an element of $\mathcal{P}[a,b]$, though I'm not sure how to show this formally (e.g. via a contradiction).

Similarly, I'm not sure how to show that $C^{1}[a,b]$ is not closed. Though perhaps the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus may be useful? I think it's possible to exhibit a sequence of differentiable functions that converge to a continuous function that is not differentiable, but I'm not sure how to do this.

Finally, for the set $\mathcal{R}[a,b],$ it suffices to show that for any $(f_n)\subseteq \mathcal{R}[a,b]$, $f_n\to f\in \mathcal{B}[a,b]$, $f\in \mathcal{R}[a,b].$ Since each $f_n \in \mathcal{R}[a,b], \int_a^b f_n(x) dx$ exists for each $n$. Also, since $f_n\to f$ under the supremum metric, $\|f_n - f\|_\infty \to 0.$ However, I'm not sure how to show that $f\in \mathcal{R}[a,b]$ from here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The set $\mathcal C^1([a,b])$ is not closed in $\mathcal B([a,b])$: if $f_n(x)=\sqrt{\left(x-\frac{a+b}2\right)^2+\frac1n}$, then each $f_n$ belongs to $\mathcal B([a,b])$, but the sequence $(f_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ converges, in $\bigl(\mathcal B([a,b]),d_\infty\bigr)$, to $\left|x-\frac{a+b}2\right|\notin\mathcal C^1([a,b])$.

The set $\mathcal P([a,b])$ is also not closed in $\mathcal B([a,b])$: if $f_n(x)=\left(1+\frac xn\right)^n$, then the sequence $(f_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ converges, in $\bigl(\mathcal B([a,b]),d_\infty\bigr)$, to $e^x\notin\mathcal p([a,b])$.

But $\mathcal R([a,b])$ *is* closed in $\mathcal B([a,b])$. It is a standard theorem about Riemann-integrable functions that if a sequence $(f_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ of Riemann-integrable functions converges uniformly to a function $f$, then $f$ is Riemann-integrable too.